# Transferring Properties from one to another object based on the value of another property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have a slight problem. I am working on an angular application and at some point i am getting some data from an api.

I have an existing object with project urls and am getting an array of timeslip objects that have an hours property and a project urls property themselves to indicate which project they belong to.

What I am trying to achieve is to iterate through all the timeslips I get in order to transfer the number of hours to the project in the project array that has a matching url property.

The project array is : $scope.projectsObject

My code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.timeslips.length; i++) {

    //SET LOCAL VARIABLE FOR SELECTED TIMESLIP
    var timeslip = response.data.timeslips[i];

    //ITERATE THROUGH PROJECTS ARRAY
    for (var ii = 0; ii < Object.keys($scope.projectsObject).length; ii++) {

        //SEE IF TIMESLIP BELONGS TO PROJECT
        if ($scope.projectsObject[ii].url == timeslip.url) {

            //SEE IF $scope.projectsObject HAS HOURS PROPERTY
            if ('hours' in $scope.projectsObject[ii]) {

                //IF YES ADD HOURS TO EXISTING AMOUNT
                $scope.projectsObject[ii].hours = $scope.projectsObject[ii].hours + timeslip.hours;

            } else {
                //IF NOT CREATE IT AND ADD HOURS
                $scope.projectsObject[ii] = { "hours": timeslip.hours };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with recognising when the hours of a previous timeslip were already added to the project and I don't want to create the hours property from new, but just add the hours of the current timeslip to the hours that were already previously added.

It would be great if someone could point out my mistake here, as I just can't seem to find it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you supply some data from `response.data.timeslips`  and from `$scope.projectsObject`? and why do you `$scope.projectsObject[ii] = { "hours": timeslip.hours };` when you can do this `$scope.projectsObject[ii].hours = timeslip.hours;`? the other way delete the `($scope.projectsObject[ii].url`.

Comment: instead of  `if('hours' in $scope.projectsObject[ii])` have you tried if `($scope.projectsObject[ii].hasOwnProperty('hours'))` ??

Comment: Really difficult for anyone here to debug without enough code and data sample to replicate. Create a simple demo that people can debug with

Comment: Set breakpoint in the code also so you can see what is what at each step

Comment: An examlple for response.data.timeslips: `[{"hours":"7.0","url":"https://api.sample.com"},{"hours":"2.5","url":"https://api.sample1.com"},{"hours":"0.5","url":"https://api.sample2.com"},...]` An example for $scope.projectsObject: `[{"url": "https://api.sample1.com"},{"url": "https://api.sample.com"},{"url": "https://api.sample2.com"},...]` I now want to move the hours to the corresponding project object in the other array based on the url. I have tried using hasOwnProperty which didn't change anything...

Comment: It seems like the function doesn't realise when there is already a value for hours. It doesn't go into the if statement that would add the new value to the old one. Instead it just ignores it... So i only get the first value for each, but no add ups

Comment: you are comparing a `.url` to a type of `.project` instead of `.project.url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a more concise code.

What has changed:

- Iteration for `response.data.timeslips`.
- Iteration for `$scope.projectsObject`.
- Test if property `url` is equal in both objects.
- Provide a default value `0`, if `b.hours` is not set.
- Conversion of `timeslip.hours` from `String` to `Number`.
- Add the values.
- Assign the new value to `b.hours` (and leave the rest of object b intact).

```js
var response = { data: { timeslips: [{ "hours": "7.0", "url": "api.sample.com" }, { "hours": "2.5", "url": "api.sample1.com" }, { "hours": "3.1", "url": "api.sample1.com" }, { "hours": "0.5", "url": "api.sample2.com" }] } },
    $scope = { projectsObject: [{ "url": "api.sample1.com" }, { "url": "api.sample.com" }, { "url": "api.sample2.com" }] };

response.data.timeslips.forEach(function (timeslip) {
    $scope.projectsObject.forEach(function (b) {
        if (timeslip.url === b.url) {
            b.hours = (b.hours || 0) + +timeslip.hours;
        }
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify($scope, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I would imagine that timeslip.hours would still need to be parsed as a float using parseFloat.  Not sure what the `+ +timeslip.hours` does.

Comment: it does exactly that. cast the value to number, see above snippet result

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if ($scope.projectsObject[ii].url == timeslip.project) {
```

to:

```
if ($scope.projectsObject[ii].url == timeslip.project.url) {
```

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry, that was a typo. Code is unfortunately still not working :(